# Setting windows to energy save mode using Node.js

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm developing an app using Electron and Node.js and is supposed to set the laptop  (running windows 10) to energy saving mode when needed, is this possible to do this using technologies of Node.js and electron? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the WinAPI function [`SetSuspendState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201(VS.85).aspx) using the [`node-ffi`](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi) library.

First, install the library:

```
npm install ffi --save
```

Then, you can use this code:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var powrprof = ffi.Library('powrprof.dll', {
    SetSuspendState: ['int', ['int', 'int', 'int']]
});

function invokeStandby() {
    powrprof.SetSuspendState(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Note that this does a normal standby and leaves wake events on. If you want to disable wake events, use `powrprof.SetSuspendState(0, 0, 1)` (third parameter 1 instead of 0). See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201(VS.85).aspx) for details.

---

**UPDATE**: Note that if you think a nice shortcut would be using `rundll32`, then you will get weird behavior depending on the computer settings and probably the weather and the day of week (as in - undefined behavior), because `rundll32` doesn't just run arbitrary DLL functions the way you think. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043) and the [`rundll32` docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787). Calling `rundll32 powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,0,0` might put your computer to sleep, but it might do something else on another computer such as hibernating instead of invoking standby mode (or theoretically even crash). So, **do not do this!**

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea which doesn't require additional libraries.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,0,0');
```

This function simply spawns a shell calling rundll32.exe so we can directly execute the function `SetSuspendState` with the required parameters.

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that this is not correct! `rundll32` cannot call arbitrary DLL functions! In fact, the `0,0,0` does *not* what you expect, instead it passes unexpected garbage to the function, because the calling convention for `rundll32` is very specific and sends four parameters: `(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR pszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)`, where `pszCmdLine` is a string pointer to the command line. So effectively you are calling something like `SetSuspendState(0xABCDE, 0x10000000, "0, 0, 0", 0);` (in C terms), which is definitely not right and will most likely hibernate the PC (if hibernation is on)

Comment: For further details, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043 (scroll down to "Rundll32.exe entry points") or the answer Raymond added to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070607-00/?p=26523#comment-512403) comment.

Comment: See also the documentation for `rundll32` from Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/164787

Comment: Thx for pointing this out. I knew about the existence of `rundll32` but never looked up it's documentation. I came across a few post which were doing the same thing so I had the wrong idea about this exe

Comment: Updated link to the comment I linked above: http://web.archive.org/web/20181011035708/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070607-00/?p=26523#comment-512403