# How to put a Win10 PC into Standby mode from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-7, standby

This code (compiled under Delphi 7) works nice under XP and Win7:

```pascal
var
  _SetSuspendState: function (Hibernate, ForceCritical, DisableWakeEvent: BOOL): BOOL stdcall;
  // Hibernate: SetSuspendState(True , False, False);
  // Standby  : SetSuspendState(False, False, False);
  function SetSuspendState(Hibernate, ForceCritical, DisableWakeEvent: Boolean): Boolean;
  function LinkAPI(const module, functionname: string): Pointer;
...

function LinkAPI(const module, functionname: string): Pointer;
var
  hLib: HMODULE;
begin
  hLib := GetModulehandle(PChar(module));
  if hLib = 0 then
    hLib := LoadLibrary(PChar(module));
  if hLib <> 0 then
    Result := getProcAddress(hLib, PChar(functionname))
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

function SetSuspendState(Hibernate, ForceCritical, DisableWakeEvent: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  if not Assigned(_SetSuspendState) then
    @_SetSuspendState := LinkAPI('POWRPROF.dll', 'SetSuspendState');
  if Assigned(_SetSuspendState) then
    Result := _SetSuspendState(Hibernate, ForceCritical, DisableWakeEvent)
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

But how do I make it work under Windows 10, too?

If I test it on a Win10 TabletPC (by calling: `SetSuspendState(False, False, False);` the device is shutting down completely.

**Update2:**

Tried to send a virtual "Sleep" button press too:

```pascal
const
  VK_SLEEP = $5F;
begin
  keybd_event(VK_SLEEP, 0, 0, 0);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  keybd_event(VK_SLEEP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
```

But the application's OnKeyDown event could not catch it, like it was never sent.

**Update3:**
*After thorough investigation of the problem during last days I've realized following things:*

1. The first code I've wrote here: WORKS under Win10 too! **But** only on some machines. :-(
2. On a (AMD) Desktop PC, it worked perfectly fine. It had an old (1709) Win10 installed, so I've updated to see if it's related to Win10 builds, but the code still worked. Also tested from User/Admin privileges: no difference! Works always.
3. Tested 4 different Intel-Atom Tablets: 1 did nothing, 2 shut down, 1 hibernated.
4. On the tablets even a simple ".BAT" file to put the device into standby did NOT work!
5. Tested all versions of .BAT + script-files (`powercfg -h off', etc...) nothing helped.
  6.

**Summarized:**
*So my first code is basically affected by Power-configurations and problems of Win10 drivers and OS.*

That's why I think the only solution would be to circumvent the whole problem by simply **simulating a "Keyboard-SLEEP-KEY-PRESS"** (as I've tried at 'Update2').

Comment: Documentation says *The calling process must have the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege. To enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege, use the AdjustTokenPrivileges function. For more information, see Changing Privileges in a Token.*

Comment: Note: your declaration of [`SetSuspendState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate) is wrong. Its parameters and return type actually use the Win32 `BOOLEAN` type (aka `BYTE`, `ByteBool` in Delphi), not the Win32 `BOOL` type (aka `int`, `LongBool` in Delphi). Also, if the function fails, use `GetLastError()` to find out why.

Comment: You've had two people try to help you, and you've ignored both of them and continued to just write code without understanding what's going on. It's time you change that and start paying attention. If you're going to ignore information that we give you, why did you post here in the first place?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the tip. I didn't know anything about *AdjustTokenPrivileges*. Opened up for me a whole new chapter what I need to learn about. But as it has turned out > that wasn't causing the problem, but the OS itself. Can it be that `keybd_event(VK_SLEEP, 0, 0, 0);` is blocked about same reason?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for for the hint, you may edit my post as you like. _(I'm afraid to mess up the timeline of progress.)_  I know about `GetLastError`, but in this case it showed nothing. _(Especially not during shutdown process it triggered :-D )_  Do you have an idea how to push through a VK_SLEEP to the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the same conclusions at this topic:
[programmatically-enter-connected-standby-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37177772/2110862)

**Solution** is to send a monitor-turn-off signal:
`SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);`